# Stream video over websocket with node

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to stream live video from my rpi (any linux machine) to my laptop using websockets (socket.io to be precise) and a node server. Anyone has done this before and can share their setup? Note: I tried taking a bunch of stills and streaming that, but it seems to be a very cpu intensive task and also creates a noticeable delay

Comment: Show us some code. What have you tried to do?

Comment: @MarceloAlves I have code for streaming stills, but I do not like that solution. So i'm trying to find a new approach to streaming the actual video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ffmpeg` to decode video-stream to `hls`-format.
This solution have a little delay (about 3-10sec) between real world and display video. See detail [**here**](http://habrahabr.net/thread/8868) (russian).

```
// index.html 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="0"> 
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Cache-Control" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <video id="video"></video>
    <script>
    if(!Hls.isSupported()) 
        return console.error('HSL is not supported');

    var video = document.getElementById('video');
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource('index1.m3u8');
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
        video.play();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
// ffmpeg example (I use rstp stream)
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -loglevel error -hwaccel auto -i rtsp://184.72.239.149/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_175k1.mov -ar 44100 -acodec aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 18 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -flags -global_header -fflags flush_packets -tune zerolatency -hls_time 1 -hls_list_size 3 -hls_wrap 4 -hls_flags delete_segments -start_number 0 index1.m3u8
```

---

```
// http server (you can use any other)
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.', {cache: false });

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  file.serve(req, res);
}).listen(1111);

console.log('Server running on 127.0.0.1:1111...');
```

Comment: lol, im actually russian, so that tutorial you linked is perfect, thanks